# Convert text into image without using buit in function

Tags: c#, image, text, drawing

can any one guide me how to convert text into image in C# where I don't want to use `drawString()` method means how to make own method to convert text into image basically what is inside `drawString()` method in C#?

Comment: Homework is meant as exercise

Comment: actually drawstring method discard shade pixels from border that is why I want to make own method because shaded pixels from border are important for me

Comment: Then please state that as your problem

Comment: You can give `FillPath` a try. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15394/Drawing-smooth-text-and-pictures-on-the-extended-g